# Use all workers PySpark YARN

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

How do I use all the workers in the cluster when I run PySpark in a notebook?

I'm running on Google Dataproc with YARN.

I use this configuration:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([
    ('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar'),
    ('spark.jars.packages', 'graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11'),
    ('spark.executor.heartbeatInterval', "1000s"),
    ("spark.network.timeoutInterval", "1000s"),
    ("spark.network.timeout", "10000s"),
    ("spark.network.timeout", "1001s")
])

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('testing bq v04') \
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

But it doesn't look like it is using all the available resources:

[image]

Here I provide some more context. The problem arises when I run label propagation algorithm with GraphFrame:

```py
g_df = GraphFrame(vertices_df, edges_df)
result_iteration_2 = g_df.labelPropagation(maxIter=5)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case a bit more? Spark will create number of tasks based on size of input and number of reducers based on parallelism set in the configuration. Perhaps you have input that does not require to use all the resources on the cluster.

If you are using Bigquery connector, note that parallelism (num streams) is decided on the server side based on the size of the data (or number of files) in the table.

Comment: Also, how many workers are in the cluster and what machine type?

Comment: @AniketMokashi it looks like it can execute in parallel GraphFrame.labelPropagation(maxIter=5).
This is a spark package and should work in parallel

Comment: @DennisHuo I've tried to add up to 100 workers (n1-standard-4 - 4 vCPU, 15.0 GB memory)

Comment: Amount of parallelism would depend on size of the input data (=vertices_df, edges_df) (and probably not on maxIter, but I will have to double check). Try playing with `spark.default.parallelism` property.

Comment: Can you share your spark-submit command? Also have you verified that DynamicAllocation is enabled in spark-default.conf

Comment: @jjayadeep 
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --region europe-west1 --cluster cluster-network-graph --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar --properties spark.jars.packages=graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11 lpa_spark.py

Comment: Okay I believe you would need to follow either one of the two options; a) Specify the number of executors or b) Enable DynamicAllocation if not already done. Without doing one of these your job will not be able to utilize the cluster resources.